# In Google Analytics, see when custom events happen during the same pageview?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, page-views, analytics-events

Is it possible to get a report that shows custom event #1 occurred during the same pageview as custom event #2?

Use case:

- Person views all slides in a carousel
- Person adds product to cart

We want to know this happened when they were on the same page. We don't care if they viewed all slides of a carousel on a different page and ended up adding to cart on a different pageview (it could be a different product).

The only way I can think of is we need to handle this in the programming on our side, and fire a different custom event. It seems like there should be a way to have GA track it on their end.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the answer you are looking for by viewing the events report but with a "segment" applied that filters out all the traffic that isn't for the page that you are interested in.

1. View the events report
2. Click "+ Add Segment"
3. Click "+ New Segment"
4. Click "Advanced -> Conditions"
5. Add the filter "Page exactly matches /mypage.html" (with the URL for the page you are actually interested in)
6. Type a segment name in
7. Save the segment
8. Make sure that it is the only segment applied (you may have to remove "All Sessions")

[image: segment]

Comment: Hi Stephen!
That means I would have to put the exact path of a specific product, right? If I used `/product/my-christmas-hat` it would work. But if I used `/product` then it wouldn't make sense because we don't know if they viewed all the carousel slides when they added the item to the cart. So I wouldn't be able to see, generally, if the two events occurred WHILE the person was on the same page. Right? I sat down with an analytics guy and he feels it's impossible.

Comment: Right.  You could see it for any specific page using this method, but you wouldn't be able to see it for all pages at once.  Conceivably you could create segments for each product, but that gets unwieldy if you have more than a handful of products.

Comment: Ah, thanks Stephen! OK, I'll mark this as the answer but we should note that in the answer, incase people don't read the comments.